# Does PureScript have a ternary conditional operator?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, purescript

Does PureScript have a conditional ternary operator?

and if it does not, is it possible to simulate one using other language constructs?

Comment: the [docs](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Syntax.md#if-then-else-expressions) seem to indicate not exactly

Comment: @depperm not sure how you can say that while linking to the explanation of the exactly equivalent thing!

Comment: @RobinZigmond purescript isn't in my repertoire. The syntax doesn't match js ternary so in answer to `Does purescript have a ternary conditional operator?` it seems not exactly. It has a way to simulate it, but as I am not an expert I linked to the docs and let OP decide if that is what they want

Comment: but it's not a "way to simulate it", it's the exact equivalent - an expression in 3 parts, that evaluates to either the second or third part depending on the truth or falsity of the boolean that forms the first part. Granted the syntax is different but that's a pretty trivial matter. (The underlying reason for the difference, I assume, is that Purescript doesn't have statements, only expressions, so an "if statement" doesn't make sense so why not use if/then/else for the useful expression form expressed in JS by ? :)

Comment: (Actually the direct reason for Purescript's choices here is almost certainly just that it's copying what Haskell does. And Haskell certainly wasn't designed with any specific reference to JS - not least because it's about 6 years older - but you can replace JS by more or less any traditional C-like imperative language and the same would hold.)

Answer (score 6):

`if`-`then`-`else` is PureScript's analog of ternary conditional operator.

```hs
x = if 5 == 5 then "foo" else "bar"
```